# How to Move a Node towards camera by certain amount - SceneKit

Tags: ios, iphone, 3d, scenekit

I'm rendering a 3d model(car) using SceneKit.

Whenever user taps on a car, using SCNHitTestResult i'm trying to add annotation(a simple plane node).

```
  //hit results are obtained using [sceneView hitTest:location options:nil]
  SCNHitTestResult * result = hitResults[0];
  if([result.node.name isEqualToString:@"Annotation"]){
    [result.node removeFromParentNode];
    return;
  }

  SCNMaterial *material = [SCNMaterial material];
  material.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bug"];

  SCNPlane *plane = [[SCNPlane alloc] init];
  plane.width = 1.0;
  plane.height = 1.0;
  plane.cornerRadius = 0.5;
  plane.firstMaterial = material;
  SCNNode *planeNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
  planeNode.position = result.worldCoordinates;
  // planeNode.transform = cameraNode.transform;
  planeNode.geometry = plane;
  SCNBillboardConstraint *bbc = [[SCNBillboardConstraint alloc] init];
  planeNode.constraints = @[bbc];
  planeNode.name = @"Annotation";


  [scene.rootNode addChildNode:planeNode];
```

Now the problem is, half of the plane(plane node added as annotation) gets hidden in the intersected node itself.
[image]
How can i prevent that... i dont want plane to be hidden. Ideally it should be circular plane. But half of it is missing. I'm thinking of moving it little bit towards the camera. Any help or suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: i want to acheive something like this "add a plane parallel to some node with some distance between them"

Comment: If half of the plane is cut off (looks like the bottom part) shouldn’t you move it up on the YAxis?

Comment: i cannot always move on Yaxis.. I should always move up towards camera n i don't know how to do this

Comment: If you want to move the node towards the camera you would need to increase the z value  e.g if result.worldCoordinates where (0,0,0) you would change it to (0,0,0 + someValue)